# Why did JSHint miss my SyntaxError?

Tags: javascript, syntax-error, jshint, pre-commit-hook

I accidentally had something like

```
var str = 'PS: ' otherStr
```

(note the lack of a `+` between them)

...and my JSHint pre-commit hook didn't catch this. So the code got shipped and when it ran it gave `SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

I know that JSHint is running because if I just put `str =` instead of `var str =` I get an undefined issue. Am I missing some JSHint option? My **.jshintrc** looks like this:

```
{
    "asi": true,
    "expr": true,
    "loopfunc": true,
    "curly": false,
    "white": false,
    "undef": true,
    "node": true,
    "multistr": true,
    "predef": [
        "$",
        "FormBot",
        "socket",
        "confirm",
        "alert",
        "require",
        "__dirname",
        "process",
        "exports",
        "console",
        "Buffer",
        "module"
    ]
}
```

Comment: If I enter `var otherStr = 5; var str = 'PS: ' otherStr; alert(str);` in http://jshint.com/ it complains: "Missing semicolon. Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression."

Comment: Via simple process of elimination, it seems that `expr:true` has a bug.

Comment: @Quantastical I don't know because I don't use JSHint, but whatever syntax error I enter, it only shows a warning. Are you sure it can show errors?

Comment: No I was mistaken. Please disregard my inaccurate comments. I'll remove them so as to not confuse other visitors.

Comment: ...however, it does show notification that something is wrong on that line since it gives `Missing semicolon` even though you have `asi:true` set.

Comment: @squit, I was just looking at the [JSHint docs options reference for ASI](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#asi) and it seems to me that setting `asi: true` will suppress (aka reduce, omit, hide) warnings regarding semicolons. Perhaps they would prefer that asi is set to false?